# jQuery slider not working on d3 multiples, but not returning error either

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm trying to add a jQuery range slider to the main chart on a page that contains small multiples of area charts, but the slider does not slide, and the charts do not transition. I'm using [the code from this block](http://bl.ocks.org/pranitar/01305d9ad0eba73dbf80) as a guide for how to implement such a slider.

Here's a link to my (semi-working) Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/zwCBQ1wR3iBlGYCMYqFe?p=preview

I thought this should be simple, since I've already set up the means for dynamically configuring the x-axis, depending on the data, with the following code:

```
var startDate = d3.time.month.offset(new Date(), -108); 
var endDate = new Date ();                              
var dates = createDatesArr(startDate, endDate);
...
var area = d3.svg.area()
.x(function(d) {
return xScale(d.x);
...
xScale.domain([
    d3.min(dates, function(d) {
        return d;
    }),
    d3.max(dates, function(d) {
            return d;
        })
    ]);

    var totals = [];

    for (i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
        totals[i] = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < dataset.length; j++) {
            totals[i] += dataset[j].values[i].y;
        }
    }
```

The code that seems to be problematic with the jQuery slider I've added is this:

```
  function zoom(begin, end) {
    xScale.domain([begin, end - 1]);
    yScale.domain([begin, end - 1]);

    var t = state.transition().duration(0);         

    var size = end - begin;
    var step = size / 10;

    t.select('.path').attr("d", function(d) {
                return area(d.values);
            });
  }
...
  $(function() {
        $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
            range: true,
            min: 0,
            max: dataset.length-1,
            values: [ 0, dataset.length-1 ],
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
              var begin = d3.min([ui.values[0], dataset.length]);
              var end = d3.max([ui.values[1], 0]);
              console.log("begin:", begin, "end:", end);

              zoom(begin, end);
            }
        });
    });
```

Here, again, is a link to a (semi-working) Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/zwCBQ1wR3iBlGYCMYqFe?p=preview

From reading [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39830232/all-brush-no-zoom) about sliders, it seems the general recommendation is to use brush/zoom to implement focus + context, [as in this block](http://bl.ocks.org/sbreslav/be9af0d809b49864b7d8/f8d0cfc6e0179042360dcd0ee707837a63412ddf), but doing so is beyond my abilities at this point. (Though I'd love to see it demonstrated.)

What I'm trying to do is implement some means of graphically (e.g. by means of a slider or brush) adjusting the x-axis/date range of the main chart, and its small multiples, such that they are zoomed or redrawn when the slider is moved. As it stands, the slider doesn't slide, the charts do not zoom or redraw, and the browser returns no error messages. Can you demonstrate a solution?

Comment: First of all, it's better to use a [focus + context](http://bl.ocks.org/sbreslav/be9af0d809b49864b7d8/f8d0cfc6e0179042360dcd0ee707837a63412ddf) . Secondly, come on man, you gotta try more than that. Wouldn't jQuery slider, in your case, have min,max and range be in the form of dates? (basically X-axis domain)

Comment: I'll do my best at implementing focus+context, then, as you suggest. As for the jQuery slider, I thought I could (and did) configure it based on the position of the dates in the array, rather than the dates themselves. Evidently not.

Comment: Get back to me if you face any issues with that. That shouldn't take long. Or we could do it both ways which'll be a good learning experience for both of us. And you could post it on [bl.ocks](https://bl.ocks.org/) as a good reference for everyone.

Comment: Btw if you check the console for "begin" and "end", those are integer values while x-axis in your case looks for dates. Hence, that wouldn't work. Changing it to a jQuery date slider similar to [this](https://codepen.io/2rod/pen/JtIki) would help!

Comment: Here's [an updated Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/X1yRlsmHoPOootO9ZJhe?p=preview) following your advice inre the jQuery date slider. Not sure why console.log returns errors for minv and maxv. I also constructed [this date slider](https://plnkr.co/edit/OF09JprgkBRM7txT5yXe?p=preview) with jQRangeSlider -- which probably doesn't have the step increment problem that the other does -- but I'm not sure the second slider is any more promising than the first until I figure how to get either of them to play with my dataset. Tomorrow I'll try to attack this from the focus + context angle.

Comment: The new slider looks perfect. It's just that you have to make it work with your dataset. I tested a part of it with your dataset and it works great. I'll add a solution link soon.

Comment: Wow— thanks! I'll stay tuned, I'm working out the Focus + Context alternative now.

Comment: This is as far as I've gotten with [focus + context](http://bl.ocks.org/sbreslav/be9af0d809b49864b7d8): https://plnkr.co/edit/MD7B9JIGoRamev9h4j31?p=preview . I'm stuck.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't work on it yesterday. I'm doing it now and will add a link soon. Seems like it requires a lot of code changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go buddy! [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/1xik1loAf1C4UiWKnMol?p=preview)

Made a lot of changes to the code. Here is a diff-check of our codes:

[Code Difference](https://www.diffchecker.com/cb76xtZw)

Relevant changes:

```
function rerenderAreaChart(selectedState, dataset, svgHook, size, begin, end) {
  var totalTicksX = Math.round(size.w / 60),
    totalTicksY = Math.round(size.h / 40);

  xAxis.ticks(totalTicksX);
  yAxis.ticks(totalTicksY);

  yScale.range([padding.top, size.h - padding.bottom]);

  xScale.domain([begin, end]);

  var filtered_indices = [];
  dataset[0].values.forEach(function(k, i) {
    if (k.x >= begin && k.x <= end) {
      filtered_indices.push(i);
    }
  });
  var max = d3.max(filtered_indices, function(idx) {
    return d3.sum(dataset, function(d) {
      return d.values[idx].y;
    })
  });
  yScale.domain([max, 0]);

  d3.select(svgHook).select('svg.state.' + selectedState).select('.x.axis')
    .transition().duration(50).call(xAxis).selectAll(".tick text")
    .call(wrap, 0);

  d3.select(svgHook).select('svg.state.' + selectedState).select('.y.axis')
    .transition().duration(50).call(yAxis);

  dataset.forEach(function(d) {
    d.values.forEach(function(v, idx) {
      v.hidden = filtered_indices.indexOf(idx) === -1;
    })
  });
  stack(dataset);

  d3.select(svgHook).select('svg.state.' + selectedState).select('g.paths').selectAll("path")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
    .attr('d', function(d) {
      return area(d.values.filter(function(k) {
        return k.x >= begin && k.x <= end;
      }));
    });
}
```

Take a look at the jQuery slider too. I've missed commenting the code which I'll do soon and update the link. Please go through the code and let me know if find any bugs or anything that isn't understandable.

And I'm sorry for the delay as I lost all the code once (didn't save it), had to rewrite it today.

One thing I would like you to make note of is it's better to use "style" instead of "attr" (attribute) for stylings such as "fill", "stroke" etc. I've changed those too.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: This is amazing -- thank you. I'm studying your code now to figure out how it works.

Comment: Great! Let me know if any part of it isn't understandable. Thanks.